# Python ElementTree: find element by its child's text using XPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I'm trying to locate an element that has certain text value in one of its child.
For example,

```
<peers>
    <peer>
        <offset>1</offset>
        <tag>TRUE</tag>
    </peer>
    <peer>
        <offset>2</offset>
        <tag>FALSE</tag>
    </peer>
</peers>
```

from this XML document I would like to directly locate `tag` in a `peer` element whose `offset` value is 1.

So for that purpose I have a XPath expression as follows:

```
./peers/peer[offset='1']/tag
```

however using such expression in ElementTree's `Element.find()` method fails and gives `None` rather than the "tag" element of my interest:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring

doc = fromstring("<peers><peer><offset>1</offset><tag>TRUE</tag></peer><peer><offset>2</offset><tag>FALSE</tag></peer></peers>")

tag = doc.find("./peers/peer[offset='1']/tag")

print tag


=> None
```

I'm being inclined to believe it's either my above XPath expression is wrong, or due to ElementTree's supporting only a subset of XPath according to its documentation. 
Looking for help. Thank you.

Comment: Your XPath expression is totally fine, it's ElementTree's implementation that is horribly incapable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `lxml.etree` directly (the same *should* apply to `ElementTree`), you can achieve the result like this:

```
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(...)
tag_elements = doc.xpath("/peers/peer/offset[text()='1']/../tag")
```

`tag_elements` will be the **list** of `<tag>` elements belonging to `<peer>` elements containing an `<offset>` element containing 1.

Given input (I've added a `<peer>` clause to emphasize `tag_elements` being a list):

```
<peers>
    <peer>
        <offset>1</offset>
        <tag>TRUE</tag>
    </peer>
    <peer>
        <offset>1</offset>
        <tag>OTHER</tag>
    </peer>
    <peer>
        <offset>2</offset>
        <tag>FALSE</tag>
    </peer>
</peers>
```

`tag_elements` will contain two elements:

```
for tag in tag_elements:
    print tag.text
-> TRUE
-> OTHER
```

**UPDATE**:

`doc.xpath("/peers/peer[offset=1]/tag")` also works fine.

But `doc.xpath("./peers/peer[offset=1]/tag")` does not.

Comment: Just trying your suggestion in `ElementTree` raises _SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element_ I see many people referring to `lxml` when asked about the use of XPath in `ElementTree`. Should I really use `lxml` instead?

Comment: personally, I gave up on `ElementTree`... and I get by just fine with `lxml.etree`.